# Extract correctly info from table with JSoup in Android

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract some info from an HTML table and put them for example into an `arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` for manage better inside my app.

I was already able to get the right HTML page saved in my `document` variable after a post request.
The following is the piece of HTML containing my useful data, but it is not the only table inside the page. I do not know how to find items into this specific table.

What would be the right approach to get data in this format: `DAY - TIME - SUGGESTION` ?

Thank you very munch in advance for any advice!

```
<table><tbody>
<tr><th class="date">Wed, 14 Sep 2016</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">09:00</td><td class="sugg">Depart and set your watch to the arrival city&#39;s time zone (03:00). Sleep as needed. The following times are in the arrival city&#39;s time zone.</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">18:30</td><td class="sugg">Arrive</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">19:00&ndash;22:00</td><td class="sugg">Seek light</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">22:00&ndash;23:00</td><td class="sugg">Avoid light before bed</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">23:00&ndash;07:00</td><td class="sugg">Sleep ideal</td></tr>
<tr><th class="date">Thu, 15 Sep 2016</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">20:00&ndash;23:00</td><td class="sugg">Seek light before bed</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">23:00&ndash;07:00</td><td class="sugg">Sleep ideal</td></tr>
<tr><th class="date">Fri, 16 Sep 2016</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">20:00&ndash;23:00</td><td class="sugg">Seek light before bed</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sub">23:00&ndash;07:00</td><td class="sugg">Sleep ideal</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

### **EDIT**

The loop I think is the way I want to implement. I am getting closer to the solution. I need to find a way to detect if the currently row I'm inspecting in the loop has th or td cells:

```
//find the table, it is the second table in the HTML
Element table = document.select("tbody").get(1);

//get all the rows
Elements rows = table.select("tr");

//loop the rows
for (Element row : rows) {

    //if the row contains th, I get the first cell and save day in a string

    //if the row contains td, I get the second (time) and third (suggestion) cells and put in my map string with day, time, suggestion

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured out a solution, maybe not the best style coded, but it works :) (Engineer: "If it works, it is good")

I have a moderate knowlege of coding in some languages, but this was the first time I had to deal with parsing and consequently JSoup. It is not a so immediate tool to understand, but in my research I noticed it is very powerful. I put it in my personal to-learn list.

Note: this approach assumes there is always th row before of td row.

This is my solution:

```
        String day = null;
        String time;
        String sugg;

        //crop the page in order to leave the table I needed, since it was without a specific id, I selected it as the second table in the page
        Element table = document.select("tbody").get(1);

        //this is the list of all the row in the table
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");

        //here I cycle the rows
        for (Element row : rows) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


            //if the row contains th elements, I store the first th of the row as day
            if (!row.select("th").isEmpty())
            {
                day = row.select("th").get(0).text();
            }

            //if the row contains td elements, I store the second and third td in strings and put all in map
            if (!row.select("td").isEmpty())
            {
                time = row.select("td").get(1).text();
                sugg = row.select("td").get(2).text();

                Log.d("row: ", day + " " + time + " " + sugg);

                map.put("day", day);
                map.put("time", time);
                map.put("sugg", sugg);
            }

            arraylist.add(map);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have two options here, you can take advantage of css selectors to pull out all the elements by class.

https://try.jsoup.org/

Or you can loop over the elements.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element div = doc.select("tbody").first();
 for (Element element : div.children()) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I decided to pursue the loop solution, but I don't understand how to identify if I am in a row with th or td elements

Comment: I found a solution. Thank you anyway for the answer ;)